# Слишком много результатов поиска на карте

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Сделал карту, где поисковая строка вынесена вне ее. Вот, когда в это поисковой строке выбираешь адрес из поисковой подсказки с конкретным адресом (города, улица, дом), то на карте всё-равно отображаются дополнительные варианты (эта же улица в городах, например). Можно как-то настроить, чтобы если есть конкретный результат уже на уровне подсказки, то остальные результаты не отображались бы?

Пример:
Запрос: Россия, Свердловская область, Екатеринбург, Орджоникидзевский район, улица Победы, 34
https://jsfiddle.net/alexeilavrov/vvu1wubf/

```
suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('searchLine', {boundedBy: [[58.29, 57.47], [56.24, 64.54]]}),
myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [56.83, 60.60],
    zoom: 9
});
```

Если убрать ограничение по зоне поиска, то начинает уже по все стране подсказывать.

Comment: Почему вы не хотите всегда использовать только первый результат? Первый результат самый точный. https://jsfiddle.net/wgr6pz0w/

Answer (score 2):

Если вам всегда нужен только 1 результат, необходимо использовать параметр `results: 1`, как [показано в примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode?from=SO).

В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так: https://jsfiddle.net/vvu1wubf/5/

Comment: Тогда получится, что всегда будет один результат. Мне хочется, чтобы не было лишних, которые противоречат запросу :) Например, когда в запросе есть Екатеринбург, то не показывало бы Верхнюю Пышму или другие города. Спасибо.

Comment: Хотя, посмотрел - нормальное решение. Проблема надуманная была.